# Python and the QuickBooks POS SDK: What string to use for the COM file?

Tags: python, windows, com, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to create an integration app between QuickBooks POS and an online shopping cart in Python.

I've found example code for interacting with the QB SDK in Python (http://blog.bflarsen.com/?p=132) using the win32 library, but it seems that this code is out of date and the string to access the COM has been changed.

The documentation has this to say:

> You can find examples of QBPOS communication in languages other than Visual Basic in  the QBPOS SDK subdirectory \Samples\qbpos. For languages that are not sampled in that directory, refer to the COM interface definitions for the Request Processor API or, optionally, for the qbposFC library. These are in the abposXML and qbposFC type libraries, respectively, and can be viewed with various object browsers, such as the Visual Studio Object Browser.

However, it does not provide the string to access the COM.

Google turns up nothing. I've searched the registry for RequestProcessor, and the only COM I can find is QBPOSXMLRPC.RequestProcessor, which does  work, but attempts to connect to a server rather than interacting with my QuickBooks, which is what I need.

My question then is, what is the proper COM file to use? If there isn't one, is it possible to turn my QuickBooks into an RPC server?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I needed to register the DLL with regsvr32.

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intuit\QBPOSSDkRuntime\QBPOSSMLRPLib.dll"
#       <"C:\path\to\intuit\install\dir\....">
```

This command needs to be run with administrator privileges.

Since this is usually in "Program Files", the quotes are necessary to contain the string in one argument.

After that, the COM string is QBPOSXMLRPLib.RequestProcessor

```
from win32com import client
rp = client.Dispatch("QBPOSXMLRPLib.RequestProcessor")
```

Hope that helps others in the future.